# Why can't I set blit=True in calls to matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation since 1.5.0?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

Since updating to matplotlib 1.5.0,

```
matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, func, init_func=func,
                                   frames=frames, 
                                   interval=1100,repeat_delay=2000, 
                                   blit=True)
```

results in

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_animated'

in matplotlib/animation.py at line 1134, which is

```
TimedAnimation.__init__(self, fig, **kwargs)
```

and I need to set `blit=False` in order to continue without errors.

This happens regardless of how I change the values of `fig`, `func`, etc, which, in any case, all worked fine until 1.5.0.

Has there been a change in 1.5.0 that causes this? Is there something I can do the continue with `blit=True`?

Comment: Is this still true in 2.0?

Comment: @Seanny123: Yes.

Answer (score 2):

In my specific case, I was animating several lines spread across multiple axes. When I set `blit=True` I saw the same error. The fix was to change the `return` statement from my `animate()` function - in the original, which I grabbed from a template, the function looked like

```
def animate(i):
...
return lines,
```

which needed to be changed to

```
def animate(i):
...
return lines  # no comma
```

The blit argument must have told something to treat each element returned by animate as an artist with the `set_animated` method - the comma would have added an extra layer of hierarchy, i.e. a list within a list instead of a list of artists.